# how to get the ESN from a specific handheld?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

how to get the ESN from a specific handheld?

thank's in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is a function called GetDeviceUniqueID

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa908781.aspx

Is this what you were thinking of ?